# trouble with functionality of custom styled input type range

Tags: javascript, html, css, input-type-range

If you drag the thumb it won't work because apparently it is not a part of input when I inspect it with devtools, new elements don't consider it's position and cover it

if you remove the paragraph after the input you can drag the thumb and the gradient will change according to it's position.

is there a way to keep the thumb working even when I add elements after the input?

if you change #slider padding the gradient will weirdly grow, if you add margin the thumb won't work again.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', ({target: t}) => t.style.backgroundSize = (t.value/t.max) * 100 + '%');
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 10%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.tags {
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

span {
  flex: 1 1;
  padding-right: 30px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: 14px;
}

span:last-child {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  /* TRACK */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #8074AE, #CBB0DF) no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
}
input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 14px;
  background: #E7E8E9;
  z-index: -1;
}
input::-moz-range-track {
  height: 14px;
  background: #E7E8E9;
  z-index: -1;
}
input::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 50%, white 55%);
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-top: 28px;
  /* You need to specify a margin in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is automatic */
  border: solid 2px #E7E8E9;
  border-radius: 0px 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
input::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  /* You need to specify a margin in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is automatic */
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Уровень владения JavaScript</h1>
<div class="tags">
  <span>Не владею</span>
  <span>Использую готовые решения</span>
  <span>Использую готовые решения и умею переделывать</span>
  <span>Пишу сложный JS с нуля</span>
</div>
<input type="range" min="0" max="1000">
<p>Help me</p>
```

Comment: The input appears to work and have the same functionality regardless of if the paragraph tag is there or not (Chrome 80)

Comment: Is your Fiddle supposed not to work? Because it works on FF whether there is an element after the input or not.

Comment: @APAD1 I added a link to codepen
try from there

Comment: @Arkellys the code snippet won't run sass, I added a codepen link, please check it out

Comment: @NastyaNastyaa for future reference, you can click the dropdown in the top right of the CSS tab in CodePen to view the "Compiled CSS"

Comment: @APAD1 thank you, that was my first question in here, I had no idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `input` in a containing element and set the `height` on that element in order to push the sibling element down below the `range-thumb` Set the `z-index` of the containing element as well so that it is above the sibling element.:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', ({target: t}) => t.style.backgroundSize = (t.value/t.max) * 100 + '%');
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 10%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.tags {
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

span {
  flex: 1 1;
  padding-right: 30px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: 14px;
}

span:last-child {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.input-container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  z-index:10;
}
input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  /* TRACK */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #8074AE, #CBB0DF) no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
}
input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 14px;
  background: #E7E8E9;
  z-index: -1;
}
input::-moz-range-track {
  height: 14px;
  background: #E7E8E9;
  z-index: -1;
}
input::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 50%, white 55%);
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-top: 28px;
  /* You need to specify a margin in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is automatic */
  border: solid 2px #E7E8E9;
  border-radius: 0px 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
input::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  /* You need to specify a margin in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is automatic */
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Уровень владения JavaScript</h1>
<div class="tags">
  <span>Не владею</span>
  <span>Использую готовые решения</span>
  <span>Использую готовые решения и умею переделывать</span>
  <span>Пишу сложный JS с нуля</span>
</div>
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1000">
</div>
<p>Help me</p>
```